# Convert Jagged String[][] to Jagged Float[][]

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

Is there an easy way to convert string[][] to float[][]

```
        string filePath = @"C:\test.csv";
        string[][] data = File.ReadLines(filePath).Select(x => x.Split(',')).ToArray();
```

Comment: data.Select( row => row.Select( cell => float.Parse( cell ) ).ToArray() ).ToArray();

Comment: your answer works, Thank you!